# Unable to set sharepoint workflow job property

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, stsadm, sharepoint-administration

I'm trying to to run the below command but error which I have never seen before. I have ran this many times never got this error.

stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname "job-worfklow" -propertyvalue "every 1 minutes between 0 and 59" -url http://connect.test.com

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: Number of daily notifications.  This value must be >= 28 and <=168

Please let me know if you have any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

This command is equal to Set-SPTimerJob cmdlet, you could try to use the below command instead. Check if this works for you:

```
Set-SPTimerJob –Identity job-workflow -Schedule  "Every 1 minutes between 0 and 59"
```